# Strange question about windows batch file

Tags: scripting, batch-file, cmd

I got **1.txt** and **2.txt** in my working directory. I use the following batch to list all the files.

The batch is this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b') do (
    echo ---------------
    set file_variable=%%a
    echo file_variable=%file_variable%
    echo filename=%%a
    )
```

The result is below:

```
---------------
file_variable=2.txt   <---------------why it is not 1.txt here??
filename=1.txt
---------------
file_variable=2.txt
filename=2.txt
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the top of your file and

```
endlocal
```

at the end.

Then you need to use the delayed expansion substitution characters.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b') do (
    echo ---------------
    set file_variable=%%a
    echo file_variable=!file_variable!
    echo filename=%%a
)
endlocal

C:\Documents and Settings\Pax\My Documents> qq.cmd
---------------
file_variable=1.txt
filename=1.txt
---------------
file_variable=2.txt
filename=2.txt
```

---

What you're seeing without delayed expansion is that the entire `for` loop is being evaluated before running. That includes the substitution, so that `%file_variable%` will be replaced with the value it held *before* the loop started. Using delayed expansion defers the evaluation until the actual line is executed.

---

There are all sorts of wonderful Windows scripting tricks over at [Rob van der Woude's site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/), containing quite a lot of different ways of doing things under Windows with various tools.

Comment: @smwikipedia: The same applies to other cases where you have to use blocks of commands, enclosed in parentheses, like `if ... (...) else (...)`.

Comment: Is there any official documents abut the difference between !variable! and %variable% notations?

Comment: @smwikipedia, check out http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ as well, it's got a lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you could get the correct output if you ECHOed `file_variable` like this:

```
CALL ECHO file_variable=%%file_variable%%
```

This approach is less flexible and probably less performant than the one described in [@paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349153/strange-question-about-windows-batch-file/5349159#5349159)'s answer. It's probably just a quick-and-dirty method of delaying the expansion of a variable without the need to enable the special syntax for that.