# Counting in a FOR loop using Windows Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can anyone explain this?  I am able to count in a loop using the Windows command prompt, using this method:

```
SET /A XCOUNT=0
:loop
SET /A XCOUNT+=1
echo %XCOUNT%
IF "%XCOUNT%" == "4" (
  GOTO end
) ELSE (
  GOTO loop
)
:end
```

But this method does not work (it prints out "1" for each line in the file).  It acts like the variable is out of scope:

```
SET /A COUNT=1
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (config.properties) DO (
  SET /A COUNT+=1
  ECHO %COUNT%
)
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It's not working because the *entire* `for` loop (from the `for` to the final closing parenthesis, *including* the commands between those) is being evaluated when it's encountered, *before* it begins executing.

In other words, `%count%` is replaced with its value `1` before running the loop.

What you need is something like:

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count = 1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (config.properties) do (
  set /a count += 1
  echo !count!
)
endlocal
```

Delayed expansion using `!` instead of `%` will give you the expected behaviour. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349153/strange-question-about-windows-batch-file/5349159#5349159).

---

Also keep in mind that `setlocal/endlocal` actually limit scope of things changed inside so that they don't leak out. If you want to use `count` *after* the `endlocal`, you have to use a "trick" made possible by the very problem you're having:

```
endlocal && set count=%count%
```

Let's say `count` has become 7 within the inner scope. Because the entire command is interpreted before execution, it effectively becomes:

```
endlocal && set count=7
```

Then, when it's *executed*, the inner scope is closed off, returning `count` to it's original value. But, since the setting of `count` to seven happens in the outer scope, it's effectively leaking the information you need.

You can string together multiple sub-commands to leak as much information as you need:

```
endlocal && set count=%count% && set something_else=%something_else%
```

Comment: wouldn't it work with only `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` minus the `ENABLEEXTENSIONS`?

Comment: @Mechaflash: possibly, I've never tried. I always have that line at the top of my scripts since I use the other stuff as well.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out this was a BIG learning experience in the meaning of "enabledelayedexpansion" and what its uses are.

Comment: `!count!` was it! Thank you for explaining `!` vs `%`!

Answer (score 27):

for a = 1 to 100 step 1

Command line in Windows . Please use %%a if running in Batch file.

```
    for /L %a in (1,1,100) Do echo %a
```

Comment: Your answer is not related to the question

Comment: this is the answer I was looking for when I searched for "counted for loop windows batch"

Comment: Me too -- this worked perfectly for me, and it's simple and elegant.

Comment: This answers exactly the question in the title. Next time, learn to summarize your question better ;)

Comment: `for /L %a in (1,1,100) Do echo %a` for pseudo ___for a = 1 to 100 step 1___ is a poor example. A better one would be `for /L %a in (1,5,100) Do echo %a` for pseudo ___for a = 1 to 100 step 5___ because it clearly implies syntax `for /L %a in (start,step,end)`

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. I have not read the question, only the topic and the responses. This response exactly answers the question. It is a simple solution, I like it.

Comment: I am more a Unix Bash guy than Windows Batch. Interesting why this `%%a`  only accepts one character, for example, `%%index` does not work. Windows makes me crazy...

Comment: This is what I wanted... I just wanted a Windows version of `for number in {1..100..1}; do echo $number; done`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch file that generates all 10.x.x.x addresses

```
@echo off

SET /A X=0
SET /A Y=0
SET /A Z=0

:loop
SET /A X+=1
echo 10.%X%.%Y%.%Z%
IF "%X%" == "256" (
 GOTO end
 ) ELSE (
 GOTO loop2
 GOTO loop
 )


:loop2
SET /A Y+=1
echo 10.%X%.%Y%.%Z%
IF "%Y%" == "256" (
  SET /A Y=0
  GOTO loop
  ) ELSE (
   GOTO loop3
   GOTO loop2
 )


:loop3

SET /A Z+=1
echo 10.%X%.%Y%.%Z%
IF "%Z%" == "255" (
  SET /A Z=0
  GOTO loop2
 ) ELSE (
   GOTO loop3
 )

:end
```

Comment: You can save the batch file and run it from the command line. You can then do a "ip.bat> ip.csv"  at the command line and it will generate a csv of IP addresses.