# Batch File Counter in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, scripting, dos

I have a for loop that I'm trying to count each loop however this loop echo's zeros. How do I get it to increment?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

set /a count = 0

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (content\docs.html) do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo %count%
)
```

Comment: Have a look a this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522740/counting-in-a-for-loop-using-dos-batch-script. The problem is that `%count%` is evaluated before execution so it will always be zero, see the other post for a solution for this.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) is a short but impressive demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a count = 0

for /f "Delims=" %%a in (content\docs.html) do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo !count!
)
```

notice the `!` instead of `%`. that's the consequence of using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

Comment: Should be `setlocal enableextensions ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: works if i use 'setlocal enabledelayedexpansion' Joe.

Comment: Although _Command Extensions_ are enabled by default allegedly, no one could presume and confide that those are enabled _in effect_...

Comment: why don't we all just move to powershell then?

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/top-ten-powershell-annoyances and 1000+ but I'm not an arbiter...