# Is it possible to know current loop index inside a for loop?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a .bat file like this:

```
@echo OFF

if "%1" == "" (
    set pattern=*
) else (
    set pattern=%1
)

for %%g in (%pattern%) do echo   %%g
```

Executing `listfile.bat setenv*.bat`, it outputs something like:

```
  setenv-win7x64-chk.bat
  setenv-win7x64-fre.bat
  setenv-winxp-chk.bat
  setenv-winxp-fre.bat
```

My question is: How can I make it output like:

```
[1]  setenv-win7x64-chk.bat
[2]  setenv-win7x64-fre.bat
[3]  setenv-winxp-chk.bat
[4]  setenv-winxp-fre.bat
```

Is there a secret variable that tells me the current loop-index? -- just like Autohotkey's `A_Index` variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522740/counting-in-a-for-loop-using-dos-batch-script

Comment: I recommend leaving behind `cmd.exe` shell scripting and use PowerShell instead. It's far superior in nearly every conceivable way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no", but you may add a counting variable in a very simple way:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%1" == "" (
    set pattern=*
) else (
    set pattern=%1
)

set i=0
for %%g in (%pattern%) do (
   set /A i+=1
   echo [!i!]  %%g
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest letting a tool do the enumeration for simplicity:

```
( for %%g in (%pattern%) do @echo %%g ) | find /n /v ""
```

Comment: Good tip, better add a @ before the nested echo.