# How to read lines from a .dll file and add numbers in the output. (Windows Batch)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a batch file that is supposed to echo words from each line in a .dll file. It works fine, I just don't know how to add numbers or letters to the front of the output. This might be confusing so I will show you what I'm working with.

Here is my for loop:

```
    for /f %%b in (log.dll) do echo %%b
```

"log.dll" looks like this:

```
    test
    rick
    sanchez
```

The output of the batch file looks the same:

```
    test
    rick
    sanchez
```

This is all well and good, but how could I make the output look like this:

```
    1 test
    2 rick
    3 sanchez
```

It doesn't have to be exactly like that, but I want it to look similar. How could I do this, and is it even possible to do this?

Comment: Pretty much a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522740/1531971 (Among others; you want to either access the "index" of the loop, or maintain a counter and display that.)

Comment: If you don't care about the format of the output then this can easily be accomplished with the `FIND` and `FINDSTR` commands. `findstr /n "^" log.dll` or `find /v /n "" log.dll`

Comment: `.dll` files are binary files - they don't have **lines**, IMO best you can do is use strings.exe from sysinternals.com to extract strings of a minimal length.

Comment: @LotPings - This seems like one of those deliberately misnamed files that's actually a text file. I usually see people use .dat instead.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!