# Batch: How to set variable in a nested for-loop and re-use it outside of it (enabledelayedexpansion does not work)

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, scope

I have a batch inside a folder whose goal is to execute all the batch files located in its sub-folders and evaluate their *errorlevel*. If at least one of them is equal to 1, the main batch will return an exit code equal to 1. This does not mean that the main batch have to exit with the first errorlevel equal to 1: all the sub-batch files must be executed anyway.

EDIT: all the sub-batch files return an exit code equal to 1 if they fail or equal to 0 if they pass (they are all batch files for testing purpose I wrote myself).

Problem: the *exit_code* variable never changes outside the loops.

I found similar problems here on SO (and a very similar one: [Counting in a FOR loop using Windows Batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522740/counting-in-a-for-loop-using-windows-batch-script)) but they didn't help (probably I didn't understand... I don't know, I'm new to batch scripting).

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set exit_code=0
for /D %%s in (.\*) do (
    echo ********************  %%~ns  ********************
    echo.
    cd %%s
    for %%f in (.\*.bat) do (
        echo calling %%f
        call %%f
        if errorlevel 1 (
            set exit_code=1
        )
    )
    echo.
    echo.
    cd ..   
)

echo !exit_code!

exit /B !exit_code!
```

Comment: What are you expecting `errorlevel` to reveal in `if errorlevel 1`? Are you expecting it to provide an error code for something in the individual batch files, or whether the `call %%f` command was successful? `call %%f` will always be successful if the file is a valid batch file, and exists, _(which must be true because it's just been returned as an existing batch file)_ I'd assume that each of your individual batch files should exit upon success with a known exit code, you could then check for that exit code, to determine if that script was indeed successful.

Comment: You need to keep the variable `exit_code` undefined.  `set "exit_code="` Then use a double `IF` to set the `exit_code` variable.  `IF ERRORLEVEl 1 IF NOT DEFINED exit_code set exit_code=1`.

Comment: @Compo I edited the question to clarify your point. I catch the errorlevel as I expect, the problem is with `exit_code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume the current directory on starting the main batch file is `C:\Temp\Test` containing following folders and files:

- **Development & Test**

  - Development & Test.bat
- **Hello World!**

  - Hello World!.bat
- **VersionInfo**

  - VersionInfo.bat
- Main.bat

Batch file `Development & Test.bat` contains just the line:

```
@dir ..\Development & Test
```

Batch file `Hello World!.bat` contains just the line:

```
@echo Hello World!
```

Batch file `VersionInfo.bat` contains just the line:

```
@ver
```

Batch file `main.bat` contains following lines:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
set "exit_code=0"
for /D %%I in ("%~dp0*") do (
    echo ********************  %%~nxI  ********************
    echo(
    for %%J in ("%%I\*.bat") do (
        echo Calling %%J
        echo(
        pushd "%%I"
        call "%%J"
        if errorlevel 1 set "exit_code=1"
        popd
    )
    echo(
    echo(
)
echo Exit code is: %exit_code%
endlocal & exit /B %exit_code%
```

A [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) is opened in which next the following command lines are executed manually one after the other:

```
C:\Temp\Test\Main.bat
echo Errorlevel is: %errorlevel%
ren "C:\Temp\Test\Development & Test\Development & Test.bat" "Development & Test.cmd"
C:\Temp\Test\Main.bat
echo Errorlevel is: %errorlevel%
```

The first execution of `Main.bat` results in exit with value `1` as it can be seen in command prompt window on the line:

```
Errorlevel is: 1
```

The reason is the wrong coded `dir` command with the directory name not enclosed in double quotes resulting in interpreting `Test` as command to execute. For that reason the `dir` command line results in following error output:

```
 Volume in drive C is TEMP
 Volume Serial Number is 14F0-265D

 Directory of C:\Temp\Test

File Not Found
'Test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

The exit code of this batch file is **not** `0` due to the error and for that reason the condition `if errorlevel 1` is true and `set "exit_code=1"` is executed already on first executed batch file.

The processing of the other two batch files always end with `0` as exit code.

The command `ren` is used to change the file extension of `Development & Test.bat` to have the batch file next with name `Development & Test.cmd` resulting in ignoring it by `main.bat`. The second execution of `Main.bat` results in exit with `0` as it can be seen on the line:

```
Errorlevel is: 0
```

Please read the following pages for the reasons on all the code changes:

- [Syntax error in one of two almost-identical batch scripts: ")" cannot be processed syntactically here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564)
- [change directory command cd ..not working in batch file after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic: [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [What are the ERRORLEVEL values set by internal cmd.exe commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987885/)
- [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)

Summary of the changes:

- [Delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is not enabled in `Main.bat` as not required here to process also correct directory and file names containing an exclamation mark like `C:\Temp\Test\Hello World!\Hello World!.bat`.
- `I` and `J` are used as loop variables instead of `s` and `f` because of the latter two letters could be misinterpreted as loop variable modifiers in some cases. Therefore it is better to avoid the letters which have a special meaning for command `for` on referencing the loop variables.
- `%~dp0` is used instead of `.\` to make sure that the batch file searches for non-hidden subdirectories in the directory of the batch file independent on what is the current directory on starting the batch file. This expression references drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of currently executed batch file `Main.bat`. The referenced path of the batch file always ends with a backslash and for that reason `%~dp0` is concatenated with `*` without an additional backslash.
- Directory and file name arguments are enclosed in double quotes to work also for names containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. `%%~nxI` and `%%J` in the two `echo` command lines are not enclosed in double quotes as not necessary as long as delayed expansion is not enabled. The batch file makes sure that this is not the case for `Main.bat`.
- The usage of `"%~dp0*"` instead of just `.\*` in first **FOR** loop results in getting assigned to loop variable `I` the directory names with full path never ending with a backslash. The usage of `"%%I\*.bat"` makes sure to get assigned to loop variable `J` the full qualified file name of a non-hidden batch file. It is in general better to use full qualified directory/file names wherever possible. This helps also quite often on errors.
- The two `cd` commands are replaced by `pushd` and `popd` and moved inside the inner **FOR** loop. Then it does not matter if a called batch file works only with current directory being the directory of the called batch file or works independent on current directory like `Main.bat`. Further it does not longer matter if a called batch file changes the current directory as with `popd` the initial current directory on starting `Main.bat` is restored as current directory which could be the directory in which files are stored to be processed by the called batch files. The usage of `pushd` and `popd` makes this batch file also working on being stored on a network resource and `Main.bat` is started with its UNC path.

The most important modification is on last command line:

```
endlocal & exit /B %exit_code%
```

This command line is first parsed by Windows command processor `cmd.exe` with replacing `%exit_code%` by current value of environment variable `exit_code` defined inside the local environment setup with `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`. So the command line becomes either

```
endlocal & exit /B 0
```

or

```
endlocal & exit /B 1
```

Then Windows command processor executes command `endlocal` to restore the previous environment defined outside `Main.bat` which results in `exit_code` no longer defined if not defined in initial execution environment. Then the command `exit` with option `/B` to exit just processing of batch file `Main.bat` is executed with returning `0` or `1` to the parent process which is `cmd.exe` which assigns the exit code to variable `errorlevel`.

Well, there is one issue left with the batch file code of `Main.bat`. A called batch file could modify the value of environment variable `exit_code` of `Main.bat` on using the same environment variable without definition of a local environment by using command `setlocal`. The solution would be to use additionally the commands `setlocal` before and `endlocal` after calling a batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
set "exit_code=0"
for /D %%I in ("%~dp0*") do (
    echo ********************  %%~nxI  ********************
    echo(
    for %%J in ("%%I\*.bat") do (
        echo Calling %%J
        echo(
        pushd "%%I"
        setlocal
        call "%%J"
        endlocal
        if errorlevel 1 set "exit_code=1"
        popd
    )
    echo(
    echo(
)
echo Exit code is: %exit_code%
endlocal & exit /B %exit_code%
```

The command `endlocal` does not modify `errorlevel`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?`
- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Hi @Mofi, thank you very much: you saved me! The problem was that I was using `exit_code` variable also in the called batch files and so `setlocal` and `endlocal` before and after the call fixed the issue. Thanks again, you've been very clear and helpful.